# How could I change the font color on the popped out window (jedi)?

Tags: coloring, jedi

I am using `python-mode` and `jedi` for autocompletion.

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:setup)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'jedi:ac-setup)

(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
(set-face-background 'ac-completion-face "black")
(set-face-underline 'ac-completion-face "black")
(set-face-underline 'ac-selection-face "black")
```

The font color show up as yellow on top of a gray background, which is unreadable. Also for the selected line, gray font on top of blue is unreadable.

I want to change the font color or the background color, if its possible.

[image]

---

[image]

**[Q]** How could I change the font color or the background color on the popped out window that show up on jedi usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [auto-complete](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete) package. Completion candidates colors can be changed by customizing `ac-completion-face`, `ac-candidate-face`, `ac-candidate-mouse-face` and `ac-selection-face`.

That window with additional candidate info can be changed by customizing `popup-tip-face`.

Comment: I have added `(set-face-underline 'ac-selection-face "black")` but nothing affected

Comment: I did the same in `emacs -Q` and selected candidate is underlined with black line as expected.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong on my end but when I say a color a different color shows up